# XSL updating an attribute with the position of its containing element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am attempting to update a document that looks like this:

```
 <document n="foo">
   <body>
      <seg xml:id="xkj">some text</seg>
      <seg xml:id="njk">some text</seg>
      <seg xml:id="ine">some text</seg>
      <seg xml:id="ocu">some text</seg>
   </body>
 </document>
```

So that each `seg/@xml:id` is updated with a concatenation of the `document/@n` and the `seg/()position` in the document.

The result would then be:

```
 <document n="foo">
   <body>
      <seg xml:id="foo-1">some text</seg>
      <seg xml:id="foo-2">some text</seg>
      <seg xml:id="foo-3">some text</seg>
      <seg xml:id="foo-4">some text</seg>
   </body>
 </document>
```

The code I'm trying is:

```
<xsl:variable name="var_val" select="tei:document/n@"/>

<xsl:template match="tei:seg/@xml:id">
        <xsl:value-of select="'$var_val' || '-' || parent::node()/position()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But it's turning out the following, repeating the same `position() = 1`:

```
 <document n="foo">
    <body>
      <seg xml:id="foo-1">some text</seg>
      <seg xml:id="foo-1">some text</seg>
      <seg xml:id="foo-1">some text</seg>
      <seg xml:id="foo-1">some text</seg>
    </body>
 </document>
```

I'm either not understanding `position()` or not traversing the XPATH axis correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: position() returns the position of the context item in the sequence of nodes currently being processed. In your case this sequence is `parent::node()`, which only contains one node, so position() is always 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position()` is not the right tool for that in the context of the template matching the attribute, you either need to `count(../(., preceding-sibling::seg))` or you can use `xsl:number`:

```
  <xsl:template match="seg/@xml:id">
      <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer">
          <xsl:number count="seg"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}" select="$var_val, $pos" separator="-"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcok

Answer (score 1):

`position()` does only work on nodesets. With the expression

```
<xsl:template match="tei:seg/@xml:id">
```

you are resetting `position()` to one at every match of this template.

So better use a `<xsl:for-each...>` which does the expected increase of the number:

```
<xsl:variable name="var_val" select="/tei:document/@n"/>

<xsl:template match="tei:body">
  <xsl:for-each select="tei:seg">
    <seg xml:id="{concat($var_val, '-', position())}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
    </seg>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Its output is:

```
<seg xml:id="foo-1">some text</seg>
<seg xml:id="foo-2">some text</seg>
<seg xml:id="foo-3">some text</seg>
<seg xml:id="foo-4">some text</seg>
```

Comment: Ah, yes I didn't realize the position was being reset to '1' with each match - I thought the position was static to the original document. Makes sense. Thanks for clarifying and the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tei="http://tei">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="var_val" select="/tei:document/@n"/>
<xsl:template match="tei:document">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@n"/><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="tei:body">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="tei:seg">
<xsl:copy><xsl:attribute name="xml:id"><xsl:value-of select="concat(concat($var_val,'-'),position())"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The code above will generate the desired output provide white space were removed from the input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><document n="foo" xmlns="http://tei"><body><seg xml:id="xkj">some text</seg><seg xml:id="njk">some text</seg><seg xml:id="ine">some text</seg><seg xml:id="ocu">some text</seg></body></document>
```